# I have Parsed Reddit posts using their API How can I extract only questions from this posts using NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, data-analysis, reddit

I want only questions from this post and want to analyze what topics are asked the most. According to the analysis, I will create podcasts on only those topics. example If I want to know what are the topics related to Stock Market on which people are asking questions on Reddit.
If I use [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/StockMarket/) subreddit I want to extract questions like "What is an ETFs?". I will create a podcast regarding such questions.
I want to extract such questions from the posts using `nltk`. How can I do that?

Sample:
I am getting JSON from [you will get data from here](https://www.reddit.com/r/StockMarket/.json) Now from this JSON I am extracting titles now I want to know which of these titles are Interrogative regex is a good option but people sometimes ask questions like this - what a lovely day. Now our conditions fail here. Can you suggest a more appropriate method?

Comment: could you post sample data?

Comment: I want to extract questions from context using nltk that it!

Comment: did you scrap reddit post? please post data after scraping or post a code how did you scrap? so that it will be easy to answer to the members.

Comment: At a very basic level you can use regex to extract all sentences that look like a question ( having '?', or words like What, When, How Who etc. in the start). Without any data sample or information on what have you tried so far. It is difficult to really answer this question.

Comment: regex fails sometime example- what a lovely day or Who cares? these are not meaningful questions is there any robust method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working a lot on text clustering, classification and so on and can give several advises:

1. **Using regexp** and check for keywords as `How, What, Where` (as [Gaurav Taneja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49044379/i-have-parsed-reddit-posts-using-their-api-how-can-i-extract-only-questions-from#comment85097211_49044379) told in comments). It is a good start. More of this you can manually improve this method by adding specific conditions. For example: question keyword must be first in sentences (or second too "And how can I...?"). `?` must be at the end of the sentence (but not always: what if anyone just skip punctuation or two sentence question: "I want to classify text. How?"). You can skip short questions (consist of 2 words).
2. One more interesting opportunity is to use **Morphological analysis**. The idea is that we need get **correct** questions to get their topics. So it must consist not only from question keyword and `?` symbol but must have additional nouns - we will catch them and try to classify (there are a lot of methods what to do with them, but it is another question). The question without them are general questions without current topic. See more info [here](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html).
3. And one more interesting way: we can get first test question sample manually and **create classifier** to find another questions from corpus automatically. Simple example you can find [here](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html) (section 2.2). There are some underwater rocks here: for example If in the test sample there were no examples of a certain (specific) type classifier would not find them. So it is useful to catch a glimpse of corpus to find new question types and add them to test sample.